# Installing Laravel in subdirectory & blocking access to it

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

Laravel have the HTML files in the `public` directory. So, if I push the source code to my site with `git`, I have to access the site via `http://example.com/public`. But I don't want this.

So, I included the Laravel Source into a sub directory named `laravel` and made a `.htaccess` file on the site root with the following code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So, any request to the root will be forwarded to the `public` directory in the `laravel` directory.

It works, but anyone can access the `laravel` directory by going to `http://example.com/laravel`

I don't want them to access the `laravel` directory. So, How can I use the sub directory installation with blocking access to the `laravel` directory ?

I already tried adding `deny from all` in the `.htaccess` file of `laravel` directory, but it makes the access to root site also **Forbidden**.

Current Directory Tree :

```
my-site-dir
    |- .git
    |- .gitignore
    |- .htaccess
    |- laravel
        |- app
        |- bootstrap
        |- public
        |- vendor
        |- and rest of Laravel Files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found a solution. Block **HTTP Requests** to the `laravel` directory.

Create `.htaccess` file in the `laravel` sub directory and put the following code int it :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule $ - [F]
```

The above rule will show a **403 Forbidden Error** when any direct request to the files of laravel directory (including index) is sent, but won't affect the `mod_rewrite` rule of the root directory's `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change your DocumentRoot/root.

Make it point into laravel's public folder, for example:

> server {
>           root /var/www/laravel/public/;
>           index index.php index.html index.htm;
>
> ```
>     server_name your.name;
>
>     location / {
>          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
>     }
>
>     # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
>     location ~ \.php$ {
>             try_files $uri /index.php =404;
>             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
>             fastcgi_index index.php;
>             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
>             include fastcgi_params;
>     }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: On some hosting providers, they don't allow you to change the Document root.